# Create n x n cell of vectors in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

In Matlab, I have a 9x9 cell variable, where each cell element contains a column vector.

How can I implement this in Python, using numpy?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use numpy rather than a list of lists?

Comment: @TheBlackCat I was hoping for a 9 by 9 grid, that I could index with a row and column number

Comment: You can do that with nested lists.  It is only an issue if you want 2D slices.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll look into that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a numpy array of python objects like this:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.empty((9,9),dtype='object')
a[0,0] = numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
a[0,1] = ...
```